# Inserting character to given places in a string for Python requests

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-requests

I am trying to use the `requests.Session.get` method in Python which can take a headers dictionary as an argument. When I copy headers from "Inspect Element" in Mozilla Firefox they look like this:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Connection: keep-alive

Host: cdn.sstatic.net

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
```

But `session.get` needs them as a dictionary:

```
{"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)
AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome",
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;
q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}
```

Is there a method in Python that takes a string and inserts characters into it at given places (in this example inserting an ***"*** to the two sides of every colon, for every new-line character inserting ***",*** to it's left and ***"*** to it's right, and a ***\*** character for line breaking before every new-line character) or just automatically converts strings of this form into a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
headers_as_text = """Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: cdn.sstatic.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"""

def get_key_value(text):
    colon_position = text.index(":")
    if not colon_position:
        return text.strip(), ""

    return (
        text[:colon_position].strip(),
        text[colon_position+1:].strip()
    )


text_lines = filter(lambda x: x, headers_as_text.split("\n"))
dict_values = dict(map(get_key_value, text_lines))
```

The final value is a dictionary:

```
dict_values = {
    'Host': 'cdn.sstatic.net',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8'
}
```